# Where is the code for "Front Page Template"?

Tags: templates

I'm using the TwentyTwelve theme.  For my static front page I'm using the "Front Page Template", but I want to modify it so it doesn't include the page's title on the rendered page itself.  So I went looking for the template file for "Front Page Template" but it's not in the theme.  I grepped for "Front Page Template" in the theme directory and got no hits.  I poked around other locations in the WP hierarchy but can't find it.

Where is it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

look in page-templates (folder) **front-page.php**

EDIT: you can find page content in theme directory **content-page.php**

Comment: omg, thx. for some reason didn't see that folder! and thx for the direction to content-page.php since that's actually what I needed to edit to fix my problem.

Comment: if you want to make front page different from other pages then don't edit content-page.php copy this file and rename to content-main.php and then call content-main.php in front-page.php like `get_template_part( 'content', 'main' );`